# MySQL group 2 different requests from one table?

Tags: mysql, request

I have table where i have position1 and position2 fields in one request i select from other tables based on position1 and in second request i select from other tables based on position2 how can i group it into one request?

1st get position1 and all additional details 
2nd get position2 and all additional details

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable INNER JOIN MyOtherTableX ON (myTable.Position1 = MyOtherTableX.Position1)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM myTable INNER JOIN MyOtherTableY ON (myTable.Position2 = MyOtherTableY.Position2)
```

Comment: e.g. one user JOHN has both position1 and position2 values assigned so request gets two different salary's (with two part of request) i dont see both of them in response,only salary from first part of request (position1) shown

Comment: just try to write some SQL out of your needs and my example, if it helps at all, and edit your question so me or others can keep helping :)